# foreach execution async download not working properly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, download

My application generates an array of strings from a text file and call a method inside the class filling the string calling it to be used as a Variable like:

```
    void listafile()
    {
        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
        client1.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://www.example.com/pack/content"), @".\pack\content");

        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@".\pack\content");

        foreach (string Pacchetto in lines)
        {
                startDownload(Pacchetto);

        }
```

startDownload(Pacchetto); is a method calling and inside it i use the webclient object with the Async download to download each file got from the array.

All seems working 50% well but when the Async download starts the Foreach cycle spawns alot of download and they kill themself before finish.

```
       void startDownload(string Pacchetto)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/pack/"+ Pacchetto), @".\pack\" + Pacchetto);
    }
```

have you got any idea on how to say to the foreach cycle to wait the finish of the download before start anotherone without blocking all the program with the "client.DownloadFile" that is not async? in this class there are a progressbar and a label that shows the progress of the download too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this (NuGet "Rx-Main").

First I'd create a function that takes a string (URL) and returns an observable of string:

```
Func<string, IObservable<string>> downloadStringObservable =
    u =>
        Observable.Using(
            () => new WebClient(),
            wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString(u)));
```

Now I can write a very simple query:

```
var query =
    from x in downloadStringObservable("http://www.example.com/pack/content")
    from y in x.Split(
        Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToObservable()
    from z in downloadStringObservable(y)
    select new
    {
        url = y,
        data = z
    };
```

I can then access the results of this query asynchronously like this:

```
query
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        /* do something with `x.url` & `x.data` */
    });
```

Now, if you're using either WinForms or WPF you'll need to observe the results on the UI thread. That's as simple as adding this one method call in before the `Subscribe`:

```
query
    .ObserveOn(someExistingUIFormOrControl)
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        /* do something with `x.url` & `x.data` */
    });
```

Easy. :-)

Comment: @Simon - That's awesome. I wasn't actually able to test the code so it's nice to hear it worked. That's one of the things that makes the reactive framework so so good. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the files sequentially you can `await` the result of the `DownloadFileAsync` operation. That will not block the main thread but still download the files sequentially

```
async void startDownload(string Pacchetto)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    await client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/pack/"+ Pacchetto), @".\pack\" + Pacchetto);
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing an async keyword on the method signature.

Comment: tks for your support too

Answer (score 0):

you can even start it sync in a new thread

new Thread(new ThreadStart(CompareVersions)).Start();